# GParted resize partition Error - e2fsck: Possibly non-existent device?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, ext4

**Aim:**

*Grow / Extend Linux root and home partition using GParted on live Ubuntu*

**Error:**

Root partition failing file system check and repair

```
GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 3.2
Grow /dev/sda8 from 18.63 GiB to 48.83 GiB  00:00:04    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda8  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda8 (partition)
start: 427542528
end: 466604031
size: 39061504 (18.63 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda8 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda8  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

Possibly non-existent device?
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
e2fsck: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda8

========================================
```

**System info:**

*Dual-boot - Linux Mint 18 + Windows 10*

GParted Screenshot Link  [http://imgur.com/cv3N6mM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOHvA.png)

**Steps I have followed:**

1. Allocated free space from windows' C drive
2. Booted from Ubuntu live USB
3. Launched GParted
4. Turned swap off
5. Moved my root partition ext4[/dev/sda8] to the left of unallocated space
6. Right click on ext4[/dev/sda8] - Check and repair filesystem ext4[/dev/sda8]
7. *Check ext4[/dev/sda8] successful*
8. Resize/Move ext4[/dev/sda8] to 48.23 GB - Apply
9. ERROR!

**What I have found:**

1. Bad Superblock Problem?
2. Logical Partition table problem?

***Please Help!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was able to **resize the root "/" partition while my OS was running and "/" was mounted.**

Root file system /dev/sda8 extended to 48.83 GB:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOQD.jpg

Contrary to what I read everywhere on GParted official docs and forums, it is possible. I have restarted my system and verified it using disk-usage-analyser & gnome-disk utility.

**Anyone knows how was this was possible?**
I'm willing to share further details.